# SQL Server 2008 , SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I am working with a database name xyz , table name a ,b, c, d. my question is if in table a name field , table b  email field, table c phone number , change/update  I want to make table d field upload to 1.

These tables has many fields, but I only want to change table d field when given three field change in three different table.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask here....

Comment: if some specific fields in any of three table change, i would like to make a change in fourth table field. Not whole table data change only specific fields, in those table . so i can update a field in my fourth table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly,
I would add three columns to table d and set each one to 1 in the update trigger of the other tables. Then, in your selects, you can set a virtual column to 1 if all three column are set to 1 in table d.

Answer (score 0):

You need an update trigger on all three tables `a`,`b` and `c` that checks if the relevant value has changed and if so updates the corresponding `upload` field in table `d`

Example for table `a`

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger 
   ON  a 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT UPDATE(name)
  RETURN

UPDATE d 
set upload = 1
FROM d
JOIN inserted i ON i.join_column = d.join_column     
END
```

Comment: Thanks, i am new to tigger , could explain lit more. or is any other way to do this?

Comment: @user - I've added an example.

Comment: can i create a new procedure for this? and call my procedure from each tables ?

Comment: @user - No. A procedure can't access the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables so you would use a trigger.

Comment: sorry let me explain more. i would like to use tigger but in my database each table using produce for different task . each table has a procedure so should i put this code in each table or create a new procedure and call it . ( i am new to this whole thing, if you can help me out. thanks)

Comment: @user643092  The trigger belongs to the table. So in your case you would create 3 different triggers for tables `a`, `b`, `c` and not alter the procedures at all. The trigger will fire automatically whenever the table is updated from any source.

Comment: IF I HAVE MORE THAN ONE COLUMNS IN ONE TABLE. THAN HOW SHOULD I PUT THEM IN    LIKE   IF NOT UDATE( FIRST NAME, LAST NAME)??

Comment: ALSO CAN I GET TABLE NAME AS A PARAMETER FROM A VARIABLE. FOR EXAMPLE CREATE TRIGGER dbo.uploadTrigger 
   ON  UPdate_ISD_Contact_Record /// HERE CAN I USE @TABLE_NAME 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT UPDATE(Day,phone, email)
  RETURN

UPDATE TBL_EI_Schooldistric 
set upload = 1
FROM TBL_EI_SchoolDistric

JOIN inserted i ON i.join_column = TBL_EI_SchoolDistric.join_column     
END

Comment: JOIN inserted i on i.RecID = tbl_EL_SchoolDistricts.RecID                                    error showing       Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updateTrigger, Line 37
Invalid column name 'RecID'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updateTrigger, Line 37
The multi-part identifier "tbl_EL_SchoolDistricts.RecID" could not be bound.